# How to convert 1 column dataframe to 8 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How can I convert a 1-column dataframe array (in python) to an 8 column dataframe?

I have tried to use Numpy reshape function as follows:

```
    data = []
    for x in range(0, 24):
        data.append(x)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    reshaped = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.columns.to_numpy(), (1, 8)), columns=["Heading1", "Heading2", "Heading3", "Heading4", "Heading5", "Heading6", "Heading7", "Heading8"])
```

but when doing so, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (8)
```

So, I'm expecting an output of
3 rows x 8 columns of numbers between 0 and 24

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What does `data` or `df` look like?

Comment: Hello @JNevill - I have updated the code - you can see that data is just an array of numbers. 1 column of 24 numbers. I need to put this in a dataframe with 8 columns

Comment: That's helpful. What are wanting out of this? 3 rows with 8 columns?

Comment: Hint: try to check the result of `df.columns.to_numpy()`, and then the result of `df.columns`. Then look up the documentation for `DataFrame.columns`. Hint 2: `.to_numpy` is also provided by the DataFrame itself. Hint 3: where the code says `(1, 8)`, what does that represent? How does that relate to the intended new shape of the data? (Sub-hint: is 1 * 8 equal to 24?)

Comment: Please try to [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) problems before posting. My first hint arises naturally from steps that you should know how to take without prompting. My second hint arises from the idea of [looking for appropriate documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=convert+pandas+dataframe+to+numpy+array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = np.arange(24)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value'])

new_data = np.array(df['value']).reshape(-1, 8)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
new_df.columns = ["Heading1", "Heading2", "Heading3", "Heading4", "Heading5", "Heading6", "Heading7", "Heading8"]
```

Output:

```
Heading1    Heading2    Heading3    Heading4    Heading5    Heading6    Heading7    Heading8
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
2   16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about what you are after, namely a 8 columns with 3 rows where your original range is spread sequentially across the new shorter rows.

```
reshaped = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.to_numpy(), (3, 8)), columns=["Heading1", "Heading2", "Heading3", "Heading4", "Heading5", "Heading6", "Heading7", "Heading8"])

   Heading1  Heading2  Heading3  Heading4  Heading5  Heading6  Heading7  \
0         0         1         2         3         4         5         6   
1         8         9        10        11        12        13        14   
2        16        17        18        19        20        21        22   

   Heading8  
0         7  
1        15  
2        23
```

Two big differences here:

1. We don't want a numpy array made up of the dataframe's columns. We want one of the whole 1x24 dataframe. So just `df.to_numpy()`
2. The shape of the outputted reshaped numpy array has to share the same multiple as the original `1*24 != 1*8`, instead we need a 3 by 8 sized array.